# flex datagrid re-assign dataprovider

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flex3

I am working on a datagrid with custom itemRenderer & [Bindable]xmllist as dataprovider. Now the changes done in xmllist are not reflected on datagrid UI until unless I re-assign the dataprovider as the same xmllist.

As the dataprovider is Bindable so re-assigning is not required.

But it was not working so I re-assigned the xmllist to the dataprovider of datagrid. It worked.

Now my problem is when I re-assign the dataprovider my datagrid flicker(refreshes). It should not happen.

1) Is there any way out to avoid re-assigning of dataprovider?

2) Is there any way to stop flickering of datagrid on re-assigning the dataprovider?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think xmlList, along with xml are not able to be bound for whatever reason, so binding doesn't work with them. You could convert your xmlList to an arrayCollection and bind to that. The flicker would probably have something to do with your custom itemRenderer, but I think we would need to see the code to know more.